# Oracle APEX RESTful does not have Test section

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a local install of Oracle XE, APEX 5.0.4.00.12 and ORDS 3.0.6.176.08.46 and I'm following this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/Restful%20Services/restful_services.html

I noticed that compared to the tutorial, my instance does not have a Test section. Is this due to a misconfiguration or possibly a version issue?

Comment: did you click on apply changes first?

Comment: Yes, I clicked all the apply changes from the REST module, to the URI template, to the Resource handler.

Comment: It is probably a configuration error, I was experiencing the same problem until I had to contact the Apex Admins to re-configure the Restful services

Comment: I wish I knew what to re-configure since I'm hosting everything in my local machine.

Comment: Check this article please https://community.oracle.com/message/13400445

Comment: @hinotf Thanks, I managed to get ORDS running with the buttons showing up. Now, I'm getting 404s when accessing the APIs. `The procedure named <template> could not be accessed` Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by:

1. Disabling the default APEX port

   ```
   EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0);
   ```
2. Turning on ORDS

   ```
   java -jar ords.war
   ```